# How to bind data from 2 ViewModel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, viewmodel

As the title said, I tried to get data from 2 different ViewModel but it shows nothing on it. Am I doing it wrong?
Here is my XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:VMContainer/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VM1.LibraryVM1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Width="150" Height="200" Source="{Binding Path=cover}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VM2.LibraryVM2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Width="150" Height="200" Source="{Binding Path=cover}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

My Container

```
public class VMContainer
{
    public VModel1 VM1 { get; set; }
    public VModel2 VM2 { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel 1

```
public class VModel1
{
    public DataView LibraryVM1 { get; private set; }
    public VModel1()
    {
        DataTable vm1 = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=library;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from index_movie_list", connection);
            adapter.Fill(vm1);
        }
        LibraryVM1 = vm1.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

ViewModel 2

```
public class VModel2
{
    public DataView LibraryVM2 { get; private set; }
    public VModel2()
    {
        DataTable vm2 = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=library;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from index_tv_list", connection);
            adapter.Fill(vm2);
        }
        LibraryVM2 = vm2.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

when I run the program, it shows blank white only. When I change it without the container and select 1 ViewModel only it shows the image but I can't view my ViewModel 2. Are there any solutions to it?

**Edit :** Problem Solved after i initialize VM1 and VM2 thanks to `Loocid` answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `VMContainer` never initialises `VModel1` and `VModel2` so you're binding to `null`.

Try this:

```
public class VMContainer
{
    public VModel1 VM1 { get; set; } = new VModel1();
    public VModel2 VM2 { get; set; } = new VModel2();
}
```